# Producer terminating with 1 message (39bytes) still in queue or transit. Kafka

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

How do I solve this terminating with `kafka`? I have the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY2j3.png

Code:

```
public class KafkaHelper
{
    public static async Task<bool> SendMessage(KafkaSettings settings, string topic, string key, string val)
    {
        var succeed = false;
        var config = new ProducerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = settings.Server,
            ClientId = Dns.GetHostName(),

        };
        using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(config).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                await adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new List<TopicSpecification> {
                    new TopicSpecification {
                        Name = topic,
                        NumPartitions = settings.NumPartitions,
                        ReplicationFactor = settings.ReplicationFactor } });
            }
            catch (CreateTopicsException e)
            {
                if (e.Results[0].Error.Code != ErrorCode.TopicAlreadyExists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occured creating topic {topic}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Topic already exists");
                }
            }
        }
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
        {
            producer.Produce(topic, new Message<string, string>
            {
                Key = key,
                Value = val
            }, (deliveryReport) =>
            {
                if (deliveryReport.Error.Code != ErrorCode.NoError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to deliver message: {deliveryReport.Error.Reason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Produced message to: {deliveryReport.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                    succeed = true;
                }
            });
            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(succeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reducing your flush duration. 10 seconds is probably too long